# convert integer to date and time in R

Tags: r, date, time, type-conversion

I have an int column with values like `30, 2230, 130` is there any function that I could convert them in time format like `30` to `00:30` and `130` to `01:30`? I used:

```
format(strftime(col,format="%H:%M"), format="%H:%M")
```

but it returned an error:

```
as.POSIXlt(x, tz=tz)::'origin' must be supplied
```

I also need to add ***yy-mm-dd*** in before the time after the time conversion so the ultimate output could like `"1980-05-28 00:30"`, `" 1980-05-28 22:30"`, and `" 1980-05-28 01:30"`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `as.POSIXct(gsub("^(..)(..)$", "1980-05-28 \\1:\\2", sprintf("%04d", c(30,2230,130))), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `as.POSIXct` and `sprintf` along with `paste` to create date/time:

```
as.POSIXct(paste("1980-05-28", sprintf("%04d",c(130, 2030, 1120, 30,0120)),sep = " "),
           format = "%Y-%m-%d %H%M")

# [1] "1980-05-28 01:30:00 BST" "1980-05-28 20:30:00 BST" "1980-05-28 11:20:00 BST"
# [4] "1980-05-28 00:30:00 BST" "1980-05-28 01:20:00 BST"
```

**Note:** The solution is something similar to what suggested by @r2evans. I tried to simplify it a bit.

Comment: this works out for my question, however, sprintf("%04d",c(130, 2030, 1120, 30,0120)) doesn't solve the problem if you have hundreds different times. let's say you have 30, 31, ........ which you can continuiously  add up ? any thought?

Comment: @NaPeng `sprintf("%04d",c(130, 2030, 1120, 30, 0120))` should work for any number of elements. Please provide me `10` such times where you think it will not work and I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response and I think I did not make my question clear. what I am trying figure out is if there is a function will have the same outcome without specifying 30, 1:30...... think about this if you have more hundered different times then you have to type each one of them and it increases the probability of human error. Hope I made myself clear this time.

Comment: @NaPeng Where is data? You have to read data from somewhere which you will convert to time. Is data in file?

Comment: I have done this in SQL just wondering if we have similar functions in R too. :)